# If a graph has order 99 then it has a vertex of even degree .

Tags: graph-theory

How should I show the following:

> If a graph has order $99$ , then show that it has a vertex of even degree.

I don't get how to prove it, maybe we need the use of fact that the sum of all degrees in graph has to be even..

Kindly help..

Comment: Precisely.  If no vertex had even degree, all degrees are odd.  The sum of an odd number of odd numbers is again odd, but that contradicts the handshaking lemma that $\sum_{v\in V} deg(v) = 2|E|$ which is even.

Comment: Can the sum of 99 odd numbers be even?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of vertices of odd degree is even in any finite simple graph.This is because the sum of the degrees of the vertices is twice the number of edges(hence even). Since this sum is even there is an even number of vertices of odd degree.If there is an even number of vertices of odd degree and $99$ vertices we conclude there is an odd number of vertices of even degree. Because of this there is at least one.

Comment: but how in this case is the no. of vertices of odd degree even. kindly help...I can't understand..

Comment: There are always an even number of vertices of odd degree, as a direct corollary of the handshaking lemma.  The proof is to assume otherwise.  If there were infact an odd number of odd degree vertices, then $\sum_{v\in V} deg(v)$ is odd and could not equal $2|E|$ which is even.

Comment: @Jorge thanks for the nice answer...

Comment: Sure, I hope it helped. I'm happy to answer any further questions if something was not clear.